# How to get the on-screen fonts in Windows 7 to be as sharp as possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts

I am trying to get the on-screen fonts in Windows 7 to be extremely "in-focus". I have played with the ClearType options but the characters seem to lack sharp edges. What settings can I use to produce the most clearly-defined character display regardless of the specific font used?

Comment: 1) Use the screen at its native resolution.  If you use screen magnification or map a lower resolution onto a higher resolution screen, the fonts will not be sharp.  Select a larger native font size instead (a generic "Large Font" setting or larger point size in the system font setting, and possibly a better font).  2)Make sure ClearType is enabled.  I forget whether Win 7 offers this, but some OSs give you the option to select the form of font enhancement that looks sharpest to you.

Comment: Thanks, I have done anything what was possible with ClearType options, but it is far from the precision of fonts I had previously. They simply do not have enough sharp edges. -- Thanks for your effort. (-:

Comment: If you display an on-screen font at its native resolution and the screen's native resolution and don't use ClearType, each font pixel is in a predefined location and that will be as sharp as you can get it.  Most people don't like the jagged edges this can produce.  ClearType smooths the edges so that the characters look more regular.  If you want the absolute sharpest characters possible, turn off ClearType.  If you don't display everything at it native resolution (i.e., use magnification or resolution mapping), the pixels are averaged and interpolated, which destroys edges and fine detail.

Comment: @slhck - I wasn't sure if editing the question automatically puts it into the reopen queue.  I'm hoping my edit clears up whatever was unclear.  If there is still ambiguity, can I get some feedback on what to fix?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's probably more opinion based rather than unclear. Unclear in the sense of what "clear" really means. That could be entirely subjective. For example, some people hate the fonts on OS X while others think they are very clear.

Comment: @slhck - Does this edit do it?  (and do edits automatically move a question to the re-open queue?)

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes and yes. I would have preferred if the OP showed what exactly his settings were, but it's answerable this way, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If you display an on-screen font at its native resolution and the screen's native resolution and don't use ClearType, each font pixel is in a predefined location and that will be as sharp as you can get it. Most people don't like the jagged edges this can produce. ClearType smooths the edges by averaging and interpolating adjacent and surrounding pixels so that the characters look more regular.  That process intentionally softens the edges, which is the tradeoff.  If you want the absolute sharpest characters possible, turn off ClearType.

Note that if you don't display everything at it native resolution (i.e., if you use screen magnification or map a different screen resolution), the pixels are averaged and interpolated, which destroys edges and fine detail. So if the on-screen characters are too small to read comfortably, select a "large fonts" setting or change the system font to a larger point size rather than using a screen magnification setting.

Comment: I like the way you explained this. I'm a big proponent of using native resolution wherever possible myself as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [ClearType Tuner](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx)  built in to Windows 7.  It can make ClearType fonts more readable.

> Windows 7 users should use the built-in ClearType tuner found in the Windows Control Panel under Appearance and Personalization to adjust their ClearType settings. Windows Vista users should use the online tuner found on this page to turn on and tune their ClearType settings from Internet Explorer. The tuner should be used with Internet Explorer because it depends on an ActiveX control. Alternatively, users can download the Windows PowerToy version of the tuner.